# How to determine if a string is between two characters w/o Regex?

Tags: python

Suppose we are given character '.' to determine whether it is between characters '(' and ')', how can accomplish this without using the re (regex) module?

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: Why can't you use regex? You want to find a literal `(.)` or just any `.` that's contained within `(` and `)`?

Comment: It's very likely that even searching for it with a regex is insufficient for your problem. Can't tell, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea, find a `.` character and then look for opened parens to the left and closed parens to the right.

```
def dot_inside_parens(s):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '.':
            return '(' in s[:i] and ')' in s[i+1:]

>>> dot_inside_parens('((.)')
True
>>> dot_inside_parens('.((.)')
True
>>> dot_inside_parens('.(()')
False
```

This doesn't take into account that the parens are balanced, for example:

```
>>> dot_inside_parens('(.()')
True
```

because there's a dot enclosed in two parenthesis.

To address this future, you can use a more complicated algorithm. Basically look for a `.` character and when found, look to the left for a *non closed paren*, then look to the right for a *non opened paren*. If you find both then the `.` is correctly enclosed between parens.

```
def dot_inside_parens2(s):
    found = False
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '.':
            aux = 0
            for c1 in s[:i][::-1]:  # iterate over the remaining string to the left
                if c1 == '(':
                    aux += 1
                    if aux > 0:
                        break
                elif c1 == ')':
                    aux -= 1
            if aux > 0:
                found = True  # no opened parens to the left
            aux = 0
            for c1 in s[i+1:]:  # iterate over the remaining string to the right
                if c1 == ')':
                    aux += 1
                    if aux > 0:
                        break
                elif c1 == '(':
                    aux -= 1
            if aux > 0 and found:
                return True  # no closed parens to the right
    return False    

>>> dot_inside_parens2('(edge.).(case)')
True
>>> dot_inside_parens2('(edge).(case)')
False
>>> dot_inside_parens2('(.()')
False
>>> dot_inside_parens2('((.)')
True
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like  this answer(+1) but `dot_inside_parens("(((.")` ... granted its hard to tell what the answer shoudl be from OP

Comment: @JoranBeasley missed that case, I'll fix it, thanks :)

Comment: Right, except in this case `dot_inside_parens("(edge).(case)")` will return `True` (I had strongly considered this implementation as well, though I was using `str.index` -- this one's better!)

Comment: @adsmith yes it does, the OP didn't ask for balanced and in my opinion, the `.` is inside the first and last parenthesis. I'm aware of that.

Comment: @adsmith I did came up with another algorithm that strictly check that, I'll include it for completeness but I think the OP just want for a dot inside to parens, without any closing or opening semantics don't you agree?

Comment: @adsmith Further on, `str.index` won't work because there can be more than one `.` in the string and `index` just return the first match.

Comment: @PauloBu I don't agree, but neither of us are OP so it's hard to say for certain! I wrote up a dirty hack that will satisfy my understanding of the question. RE: `str.index`: I know, that's why I said yours is better! :)

Comment: @adsmith I added the second algorithm that works for your case but it's kind of ugly :)

Comment: @PauloBu How is it different from mine, short of using `enumerate` and building string slices instead of using one pass through the string? :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your contribution to my question! I have accepted Paulo's solution as it does exactly what I wanted it to do and comes with a clear explanation! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought of a very simple implementation. Start with:

```
string_list = initial_string.split(".")
```

This produces a list of strings, where the boundary between each string is a ".". In the simple case where there is only one "." in the string, then we only need to see if "(" is in string_list[0] and if ")" is in string_list[1]. Or in other words

```
(string_list[0].find("(") + 1) and (string_list[1].find(")") + 1)
```

The '+ 1's are there because string.find() returns the lowest index of a match, so if the string is e.g. "(", then find would return 0, and 0 == False.

For more complicated parsing, we need more to go on... Should "(..)" return true? Should ".(.)" return true? Should ")(.)" return true? Should "().)" return true? The above process could be extended to handle those cases, but listing all the possible implementations for each case would take a lot of space and time.

Answer (score -1):

Well, here's the ugliest hack I've ever written.

```
depth = 0
for i,character in enumerate(mystring):
    if character == "(": depth += 1
    elif character == ")": depth -= 1
    # you may want to ignore any closing parens with no open parens, in
    # which case you'd do depth = max(0, depth-1)
    elif character == '.' and depth > 0 and ")" in mystring[i+1:]:
        # this period is between parens
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand how this will work. First, it's not complete, second, what happens with this case: `"(."`? `.` is found and depth greater than 0...

Comment: @PauloBu I left implementation details of what to do if a `.` is found up to the OP. However you're right I need to track to make sure a close paren exists: I had assumed balanced parens. Fixed.

Comment: That was the starting of my headaches in my first answer noticed by @JoranBeasley. You can see the comments and the edit history. I see you edit but have the same problem than my first version. What about this? `"(.()"`? Wasn't that what you criticized in my first algo? :D Even your test case `(edge).(case)` won't work. When `.` is found depth is 0.

Comment: @PauloBu since depth is zero, it doesn't find that match. I don't consider `(edge).(case)` to be a match

Comment: Isn't `(.()` a match? It's contained within all balanced parens.... It's incredibly difficult to guess what OP wants, so I think we're both doing our best with it. I would consider `(.()` to be a match, which it does by my algo. I just have to keep safe the edge case that `depth>0`, `character==0` but `i+1` throws `IndexError`. No time to muck with that though -- headed home.